# Set Language for Bot framework Webchat Window

Tags: botframework, bots

IE does not present my Webchat window in the correct language, which happens properly in Chrome.

In IE the webchat shows me the "enter your text" message in PL language

It would be good to have a workaround for this.

How do I change the message to English language by default.

See this capture:
[image]

Comment: This question is liable to be put **on hold** since you provided a "enter image description here" link to an image of your error, and also your image doesn't provide much (if any) evidence. Therefore, it is unclear what you are asking, and your question requires urgent attention (due to the negative score).

Comment: "different view on IE and Chrome": which difference? "IE system show me message in PL language": and the problem is? the encoding? the language?
Please clarify your question

Comment: Hi @jolwin, any updates? I'd like to know if the solution that I shared in reply can help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to set the language for the webchat window itself (text in locations like what you've circled) just add the "locale" field to your BotChat.App call.

This should look something like the following:

```
BotChat.App({
directLine: { secret: "<secret>" },
user: { id: <userid> },
bot: { id: "<botid>" },
locale:"en_US", //new field, just enter whichever locale you'd like the webchat to be in.
resize: 'detect'
}, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> In IE the webchat shows me the "enter your text" message in PL language

I can reproduce the issue if I change **Language Preferences** of browser: move `Polish` to the top of Language Preferences list, the placeholder value would be displayed same as your capture.

[image]

> How to change the massage to English language default.

To make the message display in English, please try to remove or move down `Polish` from language preferences list.